# OpenGL Font Lib

Tags: opengl

I find a simple (and portable) lib for integrate in a my OpenGL based game.

more simple and little of FreeType?

thanks

Comment: Try [glFont](http://massimobortolato.github.io/glFont), it is portable, simple and effective

Answer (score 2):

Try [FTGL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftgl/). Its portable, simple in use and can render 3D fonts. But it uses FreeType2.

Answer (score 1):

If your using QT, there's a built in font rendering subsystem, assuming you've sub classed QGLWidget, there is a set of text rendering methods you can call

If you don't find a library, you could always render the text out to an image using photoshop, and then use it as a texture atlas, and render textured quads out

Answer (score 0):

Try [FreeType](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/freetype.htm), here is a [NeHe lesson](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=43) on how to use it in an OpenGL program.

Comment: hanks FreeType is good approoch.

in my plans i port my app in some plataforms (PC, iPhone, PlayStation, etc..)

FreeType is plataform-indepent.

the hard part is integrate freetype in my proj

Comment: Oops, I haven't noticed that you mentioned you didn't want "FreeType"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use FreeType, I have a simple OpenGL example of how to use it. I render glyphs to a glyph cache that is backed by a texture. Then I draw the text using simple texture mapped quads.

https://github.com/ccxvii/snippets/blob/master/glfont.c

If you don't want to use FreeType, you can trivially replace it with Sean Barret's stb_truetype.h truetype font rasterizer:

http://nothings.org/stb/stb_truetype.h